# Return next line from a string_view source as a string_view

Tags: c++

Is there an existing facility to iterate over lines of an `std::string_view` such that the lines returned are also `std::string_view`, and thus no copies are made from the source.

In sudo code:

```
std::string_view GetNextLine(StringViewStream svs) {
    return GetLine(svs);
}
```

Comment: [`std::views::split('\n')`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/split_view)?

Comment: If you can't use C++20 then I have this for you (I needed a function like that myself a while back so I wrote it) : https://onlinegdb.com/nH-9MwOGs

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to do the parsing myself, but it seems it's not too difficult. Will do it manually.